# How to Convert Oracle to MS SQL Server - PIVOT and STRING_AGG

Tags: sql-server, oracle, pivot-table, database-migration, string-agg

Please help me convert Oracle into SQL Server PIVOT.

The table_cases contains these data:
[image]

And the expected result is below. Note: I just short-cut the columns "hour-Nth" for "hour-01" to "hour-24" columns.
[image]

Oracle:

```
SELECT 
  "column_user_id", 
  "column_user_name", 
  "column_cases", 
  "column_number_hour", 
  "column_number_index"
FROM 
  table_cases 
  /* Use Pivot to flip the time windows */
  PIVOT (
    listagg(column_cases, ',') within group(
      order by 
        column_number_hour
    ) for column_number_index in (
      0 as "Hour-01", 1 as "Hour-02", 2 as "Hour-03", 
      3 as "Hour-04", 4 as "Hour-05", 5 as "Hour-06", 
      6 as "Hour-07", 7 as "Hour-08", 8 as "Hour-09", 
      9 as "Hour-10", 10 as "Hour-11", 11 as "Hour-12", 
      12 as "Hour-13", 13 as "Hour-14", 14 as "Hour-15", 
      15 as "Hour-16", 16 as "Hour-17", 17 as "Hour-18", 
      18 as "Hour-19", 19 as "Hour-20", 20 as "Hour-21", 
      21 as "Hour-22", 22 as "Hour-23", 23 as "Hour-24"
    )
  )
```

When I tried to convert it to SQL Server like this. I made a temporary table for this example only if it helps understand my question.

```
CREATE TABLE #table_cases (
    column_user_id nvarchar(10),
    column_user_name nvarchar(50),
    column_cases int,
    column_number_hour int,
    column_index_hour int
)

INSERT INTO #table_cases (column_user_id, column_user_name, column_cases, column_number_hour, column_index_hour)
VALUES ('AAA111', 'Shelby, Marie', 5, 9, 0); 

INSERT INTO #table_cases (column_user_id, column_user_name, column_cases, column_number_hour, column_index_hour)
VALUES ('BBB222', 'Wayne, Johnny', 15, 10, 1); 

INSERT INTO #table_cases (column_user_id, column_user_name, column_cases, column_number_hour, column_index_hour)
VALUES ('BBB222', 'Wayne, Johnny', 51, 9, 0); 

SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         "column_user_id", 
         "column_user_name", 
         "column_cases", 
         "column_number_hour", 
         "column_number_index"
     FROM 
         #table_cases) AS TABLE_1
  /* Use Pivot to flip the time windows */
 PIVOT (
    STRING_AGG( TABLE_1."column_cases", ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TABLE_1."column_number_hour")  
    for TABLE_1.column_number_index in (
      0 as "Hour-01", 1 as "Hour-02", 2 as "Hour-03", 
      3 as "Hour-04", 4 as "Hour-05", 5 as "Hour-06", 
      6 as "Hour-07", 7 as "Hour-08", 8 as "Hour-09", 
      9 as "Hour-10", 10 as "Hour-11", 11 as "Hour-12", 
      12 as "Hour-13", 13 as "Hour-14", 14 as "Hour-15", 
      15 as "Hour-16", 16 as "Hour-17", 17 as "Hour-18", 
      18 as "Hour-19", 19 as "Hour-20", 20 as "Hour-21", 
      21 as "Hour-22", 22 as "Hour-23", 23 as "Hour-24" 
    )
  ) AS PIVOT_TABLE_1
```

I get the following errors:

> Error: Incorrect syntax near ';'

The `ORDER BY` on line `ORDER BY TABLE_1."column_number_hour"` also shows an error.

The "0" on the line -> `0 as "Hour-01"` also throws an error.

In Oracle the function "listagg" works well in the `PIVOT` function. But in SQL Server, can we use `STRING_AGG` inside the `PIVOT` as aggregate function?

Because it seems to get error. The intention to put alias in the column_number_index "in" also shows error, would it be possible?

Comment: Check the syntax for pivot if you want to know how to use it. If you need help translating query, its better to post some data and expected results, since few people are both well versed in oracle + mssql at the same time

Comment: @ThomA thanks for your reply. The Oracle version is working correctly, I'm just trying to convert it to SQL Server. Oracle's function "listagg" have equivalent SQLServer function "STRING_AGG" right? Please shed some more light?

Comment: As already suggested, show your source data and expected result. Since you want help constructing a query that works in SQL Server, it doesn't really matter that you have a query that works in Oracle (except to the 7 people on earth who are good at both).

Comment: `STRING_AGG` isn't a supported operator in the `PIVOT` clause. Honestly, I would suggest using conditional aggregation.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot and data and temp table and inserts to help understand better hopefully. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The two issues I see are (1) SQL Server `PIVOT` does not support the `STRING_AGG()` function and (2) SQL Server does not allow direct aliasing of the values in the `FOR` clause of the `PIVOT`.

The first issue can be resolved by performing a `GROUP BY` and `STRING_AGG()` separately and then feed that into the `PIVOT`. The second issue can be resolved by aliasing the `PIVOT` columns in the final select.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    column_user_id, 
    column_user_name,
    [0] as [Hour-01],  [1] as [Hour-02],  [2] as [Hour-03], 
    [3] as [Hour-04],  [4] as [Hour-05],  [5] as [Hour-06], 
    [6] as [Hour-07],  [7] as [Hour-08],  [8] as [Hour-09], 
    [9] as [Hour-10],  [10] as [Hour-11], [11] as [Hour-12], 
    [12] as [Hour-13], [13] as [Hour-14], [14] as [Hour-15], 
    [15] as [Hour-16], [16] as [Hour-17], [17] as [Hour-18], 
    [18] as [Hour-19], [19] as [Hour-20], [20] as [Hour-21], 
    [21] as [Hour-22], [22] as [Hour-23], [23] as [Hour-24] 
FROM (
    SELECT
        TABLE_1.column_user_id, 
        TABLE_1.column_user_name,
        TABLE_1.column_number_index,
        STRING_AGG(TABLE_1.column_cases, ';')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TABLE_1.column_number_hour)
            AS aggregated_cases
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            column_user_id, 
            column_user_name, 
            column_cases, 
            column_number_hour, 
            column_number_index
        FROM table_cases
    ) AS TABLE_1
    GROUP BY column_user_id, column_user_name, column_number_index
) G
PIVOT (
    MAX(G.aggregated_cases)  
    FOR G.column_number_index IN (
        [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11],
        [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]
    )
) AS PIVOT_TABLE_1
```

Note that the above uses `[quoted]` style identifiers where needed, as seems to be more customary in SQL server, but `"quoted"` style identifiers can also be used.

Sample results:

| column_user_id | column_user_name | Hour-01 | Hour-02 | Hour-03 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA111 | Shelby, Marie | 5 | *null* | *null* | ... |
| BBB222 | Wayne, Johnny | 51 | 15 | *null* | ... |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I1dFIEaj) for a working example.

(Side note: Check your usage of `column_number_index` vs `column_number_hour`. The current usage just seemed odd to me.)

Comment: @T N - Your solution works correctly! Wow you are amazing! I've been working on this for awhile already and no wonder I can't fix it earlier because the points you mentions are limitation in SQLServer. I learned something new. Thank you very much.